# Can't press Windows key using Robot

Tags: java

I am pressing some keys on keyboard(and buttons on mouse) remotely using socket and java Robot class.

Homebrew program is running on my Nintendo Wii.(but in here, I am using emulator)
Wii sends Wii remote button info through socket, and java program receives it and presses key or controls mouse.

Everything seems working well, except for Windows key.
It receives key press as well as home button.(and PC should open windows menu when I press home button)
So, I think the problem is in pressing key.

I press the key using this method.
if Press is true It presses the key. Otherwise, It releases the key.

```
private static void PressKey(Robot R, int Key, boolean Press)
{
    if(Press)
        R.keyPress(Key);
    else
        R.keyRelease(Key);
}
```

And I called like this:

```
PressKey(rBot, KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS, BH);
```

- rBot is:

  Robot rBot  = new Robot();
- BH is true when home button is pressed, false when home button is not pressed

How can I fix this?

Comment: did you try to press and release ?if you press hold windows key nothing will happen.you may need to release it. try 
`PressKey(rBot, KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS, true);`
`PressKey(rBot, KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS, false);`

Comment: @FastSnail Releasing HOME button will release the windows key... But I didn't checked that windows key is actually released. On Minecraft, It detects as meta key when I press the button on key settings in Minecraft. And it works well.(Maybe this mean holding/releasing work?)